# jwrapper offline windows, fails with "Could not create the Java virtual machine"

Tags: java, windows, jwrapper

jwrapper for osx and linux are working fine, but the offline windows build fails with this message. The wrapper log says

```
Trying to load library C: --- blah blah blah --- /bin/client/jvm.dll
Unable to load second library.
[ERROR] Unable to load JRE library!
Return code for JNI launch was 1
...
Attempting spawn launch
...
+++Start: Spawn launch
...
[Utils] Closing logging file
```

The GeneralUpdater log shows a PKIX cert error on the update url, but appears to continue after the error. The cert is valid, btw, so I don't know why it's complaining.

The last line is

```
*** launched, exiting in 0.5...
```

UPDATE

From a command prompt, the bundled java.exe throws an error when passed -Xmx4G. This appears to be because it's a 32 bit jre. I was using the 1.6 jre pack. This version doesn't appear to support the -d64 flag, so I switched to the 1.7 jre pack. jwrapper didn't notice that I'd changed the paths to the jres, and continued building bundles with 1.6 until I deleted everything from the build directory. At that point it built a bundle with a 1.7 jre. This jre recognizes the -d64 flag, but exits with "This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM".

Wondering why the jrepacks do not include 64 bit windows builds. Also wondering, if I get this working, if there's a way to set the memory options differently for 64 and 32 bit hosts.

Answer (score 0):

What path are you specifying for the Windows JRE tag in your jwrapper XML?  Is it a JVM you have downloaded and used?  Also what vendor is it from and does it contain the bin/client/jvm.dll structure in its bin folder?

Comment: I'm using the jre packs (1.6 and 1.7) from the jwrapper site. I suspect the problem is I'm pointing to a 32 bit jre, and requesting 4g of memory. On the command line, the installed java.exe throws a size error on -Xmx4g. However jwrapper never reports or logs this error, so maybe it's something else. I'll try a 64 bit jre.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the 32 bit jre. Switching to a 64 bit jre resolved the issue. It's worth noting that jwrapper loses these errors. They do no get logged anywhere. This is problematic.